# How to speed up deep hierarchy used in a matrix

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I'm working on trying to improve the performance of a PowerBI report. it has a couple of slicers (one for time period, one for location), and then it has a Product hierarchy with 7 levels on rows, and then 8 measures in the matrix. Performance is awful.
I saw ZebraBI guy basically warn that deep hierarchies are sloooowwwww, but what's the best way to fix this? I can shorten the hierarchy and then I guess drill through to another page... Do I have any other options?

None of my measures on the matrix are super complex. I've stripped out every iterator I can.

Do I just use the Analyzer tool to figure out what's slow and go from there?

The hard part is that the crazy deep drilldown is handy for exploring Sales... (sales per linear foot of retail space etc), and it feels like I lose something if I break that report into pieces that consume fewer resources.

Any suggestions on where to start? I'm thinking Analyzer and see where it's slow, but if I remove some levels of the hierarchy, it's not near as slow. Is drill-through my best option?
Thanks!

Comment: Difficult to say without a sample .pbix. I would post the matrix query into DAX Studio and look at the query plan. Even DAX that looks simple can incur massive performance bottlenecks (things like IF eager evaluation).

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but How/where do I upload my file?

Comment: Upload to any external site and update your question with a link.

Comment: Okay, this thing is ridiculous huge. That's how I got it. (Don't try to look at the PowerQuery... you could be there for an age!)  The file is here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhseLBH5Ic4Ii0uZiA5jc4EPPQ82?e=latVmD

Go to the "Cover" tab and there's a little explanation. The problem child is "Total Sales" dashboard. It works, but the drilldown is glacial slow.

What are my options to fix it?

Comment: I ran Performance Analyzer on it, and for the first few levels, this is what I get:
Drilldown     6,562 ms  [Category]
Drilldown   42,765 ms   [Division]
Drilldown <visual has exceeded the available resources>

And that's only 3 of the 8 levels.

(I inherited this ugly baby, it wasn't me!)

Comment: Sorry but this would take hours to debug. The first two measures are fine but when you add Net Margin £ per LMPW, the problems begin. Unfortunately, this references measures which in turn references measures and on and on. It would take too long for me to unpick. What I would advise is add one measure at a time to see where the culprit is. Distinct counts are very slow and should be avoided for instance.

Comment: Understood! It's a really ugly baby.
I guess I'll see if I can trace the nested measures and see where that gets me.
Thanks!

Comment: I think I got one of the ugly measures fixed. As far as I can tell, these two measures return the same result. (Just takes absolutely forever with the original measure on the matrix):

Original Measure:
SKU Count with Sales = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[ProductKey]),FILTER(Sales,Sales[SalesUnits]>0))

Modified Measure:
SKU Count W Sales TEST = 
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS('Products'),
            FILTER(
                RELATEDTABLE(Sales),
                Sales[SalesUnits]>0
            )
        )

Are they logically the same?

Comment: Hard to see without testing. The fact you got rid of the distinct count is a good thing though - you should not need to distinct count ids as they should be distinct anyway.